# How to use Do-While Loop to construct the program

Tags: java, oop

```
public static double avgArry(double[] a) {
        double sum = 0;
        double average = 0;
        int i =0;

        while(i<a.length) {
        sum += a[i] ;
        average = sum / a.length;
        ++i;
    }
        return average;
}   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
double j;
        double[] array = {1.5, 20.3, 4.5, 5.5, 10.3, 450, 20.4, -22.3};

        j = avgArry(array);

        System.out.format("The average is: %.3f" , j);


}


}
```

The program above calculates the average of elements in an array. But my issue is how can I put it in Do-While loop? While loop and for-loop have been done by me. Please help me out :,,,(. Please don't judge me I'm new to Java.

The average is: 61.275

Comment: be aware of the edge case that the argument has zero elements inwhich case the avg is not defined and you should consider returning `Double.NaN` which means _not a number_

Comment: which argument you talking about?

Comment: _"which argument you talking about?"_ the argument of the `avgArry` methode.

Comment: I mean I can use exception handling but still don't understand how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. Keep in mind for this to work you need to have at least one element in your array

```
  do{
       sum += a[i] ;
       average = sum / a.length;
       ++i;
    }
    while(i<a.length);
```

Comment: Thanks brother . I appreciate your help. But I felt it didn't make sense to use Do-While Loop. I would rather use For-each/While loop than do-while.

Comment: It rarely makes sense to use a do-while loop. 99% of the time for loop or a normal while loop does the work. If this answered your question please accept is as an answer.

Comment: Like at least if there's more than 1 set of instruction then I can use Do-While loop